# Intel Assembly program using function

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

i'am new to assembly and have been stuck with this program where a simple add function is used which takes two inputs and gives the sum.
The output i get now is always 0.
I think it has got to do with how the datatype is being handled.
Any help is appreciated.

NOTE:The program works fine without a function

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib



.data

msg1 db "Please enter first number ",0
msg2 db "Pleae enter second number ",0
input1 db 10 DUP(0)
input2 db 10 DUP(0)
sum dword 0
sums db 10 DUP(0)
msg3 db "The sum of your numbers is :",0
temp1 dword     0
temp2 dword     0



fsum PROTO :dword, :dword, :dword

.code


start:

    invoke StdOut , addr msg1
    invoke StdIn , addr input1,10
    invoke StdOut , addr msg2
    invoke StdIn , addr input2,10


    ;Strip CRLF
    invoke StripLF, addr input1
    invoke StripLF, addr input2


    ;string to int

    invoke atodw, addr input1
    mov temp1,eax
    invoke atodw , addr input2
    mov temp2,eax

    ;Function CALL
    invoke fsum, addr temp1,addr temp2,addr sum




    ;int to string
    invoke dwtoa,sum, addr sums

    ;Printing OUTPUT
    invoke StdOut, addr msg3
    invoke StdOut, addr sums

    invoke ExitProcess, 0

    ;Function Definition

    fsum PROC x:DWORD , y:DWORD , z:DWORD

    mov eax,x
    add eax,y
    mov z,eax

    ret
    fsum endp

end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in passing the first two arguments by address. Nor is there any real point in having an output parameter when you could just return the result instead.

So a more reasonable approach would be:

```
invoke fsum, temp1, temp2
; The sum is now in eax

...

fsum PROC x:DWORD , y:DWORD
    mov eax,x
    add eax,y
    ret 
fsum endp
```

---

If you absolutely insist on having an output parameter you would still have to make some minor changes:

```
; First two arguments are passed by value; last one by address
invoke fsum, temp1,temp2,addr sum

...

fsum PROC x:DWORD , y:DWORD , z:DWORD
    mov eax,x
    add eax,y
    mov edx,z       ; Get the address to write to
    mov [edx],eax   ; ..and write to it.
    ret
fsum endp
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael,Just to clarify,can you tell me the difference between passing arguments with and without address.                                                 Eg:-invoke fsum,addr temp1 and invoke fsum,temp1

Comment: Passing by address doesn't really make any sense for scalar types that are only going to be used as inputs. If your arguments are structs/arrays or output parameters, then pass by address, otherwise pass by value.

Comment: To be able to get the value of an argument passed by address, you first have to load the address into a register, and then load the value from that address. So you'd be introducing an unncessary load operation compared to if you had passed by value.

Comment: Thanks,makes sense.